# How to config separated webserver and Mailserver?

Tags: webserver, domain, mail-server

i register my domain at strato.com and set strato server as master dns server for my domain. My webserver is running at pagodabox.com . I have configured the A Record of my domain to point to pagodabox's IP. Everything works fine, when i enter mydomain.com in my browser, i can see my website. But how can i configure my email (something like myname@mydomain.com) to use my strato's mail server because i don't have mailserver at pagodabox.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your DNS server, you need to add two records.

The first is an A record, and will look something like this:

```
mail.mydomain.com. 14400 IN  A <ip address of strato>
```

This defines a new record that will resolve to the strato IP address

The next is:

```
mydomain.com. 14400 IN MX 10 mail.mydomain.com.
```

This will say that any email for mydomain.com should be delivered to the server at mail.mydomain.com - ie strato.

In each case the `14400` is the TTL of the record, or time to live.  This dictates how many seconds the record can be cached for by other DNS servers (also known as propagation time).

The `10` in the MX record is the priority.  You can define multiple email servers for a domain and the MX record priority tells emails servers the order in which they should be tried.

The `IN` part of the record just means INternet - it will always be this for common scenarios.